# Replace more complex nested for loops with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8

My loops are more complex than normally and before I even try harder to implement it I would like to hear whether it's possible.

```
if (emailClicks != null  && emailsOfContactsWhoFitDynConFilter != null) {
            for (String email : emailsOfContactsWhoFitDynConFilter) {
                for (Contact contact : emailClicks.items) { 
                    String queryStringActivity = getQueryStringByName("elqTrackId", (contact.link).split("\\?",-1)[1]);
                    String queryStringDynConLink = getQueryStringByName("elqTrackId", linkInDynamicContent.split("\\?",-1)[1]);
                    if (email.equals(contact.EmailAddress) && (contact.link).split("\\?")[0].equals(linkInDynamicContent.split("\\?")[0])) {
                        if (queryStringActivity !=null && queryStringDynConLink!=null && queryStringActivity.equals(queryStringDynConLink)){
                            count++;
                            break; 
                        }else if (queryStringActivity==null || queryStringDynConLink ==null){
                            count++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Perhaps you might help me to optimize it with some other method. I just experience extreme time consumption here when arrays are too big (approx. 20 000)

Comment: I would start by looking at `.split("\\?")`. This can have a major performance impact, especially that you do it a lot of times. Before switching to Stream, try to evaluate what's taking time and where the overhead is.

Comment: It seems to me `String queryStringDynConLink = getQueryStringByName("elqTrackId", linkInDynamicContent.split("\\?",-1)[1]);` is repeated too many times: put this line out of the loops. Also `(contact.link).split(...)` may be called once per iteration instead of twice.

Comment: You should not use streams to replace `for` loops, that's a misconception. Use streams to ease your work or when they're really needed. Also, you need to know that you cannot modify variables inside `Stream#each`, so counting won't work there and you will probably need to do more changes to your code. I would suggest to have proper unit tests for this code before even attempting to rewrite it using streams.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thank you, but I think streams are faster as they might be parallel, right?

Comment: You can use `ExecutorService` to add parallelism in a `for` loop, it will be more verbose but the result will be the same.

Comment: Super, thank you for the tip.

Comment: @Tunaki, actually splitting by `"\\?"` pattern is a fast-path in String.split implementation. While this step could be further optimized, it's not insanely slow. The problem in whole class design. This is a canonical example of [stringly-typed code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped).

Answer (score 2):

- As already mentioned in the comments: `linkInDynamicContent.split("\\?",-1)` can be done once outside of both loops as `linkInDynamicContent` never changes
- You split your `contact.link` which takes time and then don't use it, if this condition `if (email.equals(contact.EmailAddress)` fails.

  The biggest problem I see is, that you are basically doing a "nested loop join" for `email join contact on email.id = contact.email` which has a runtime of *n * m* for *n* being the amount of emails and *m* the amount of contacts.
  And you don't use the email after all. You you do your inner loop for every combination of email and contact. But only one time, when the contact.email matcher your email from the first loop you actually do something.
  Try changing your structure to something like this:

  ```
  String[] linkInDynamicContentSplit = linkInDynamicContent.split("\\?",-1);

  if (!emailsOfContactsWhoFitDynConFilter.isEmpty()) {
      for (Contact contact : emailClicks.items) {
          if(emailsOfContactsWhoFitDynConFilter.contains(contact.EmailAddress));
          // your code
          String queryStringActivity = getQueryStringByName("elqTrackId", (contact.link).split("\\?",-1)[1]);
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I need both loops as I need to loop through every email address of all contacts fitting a custom filter. That outer loop I am talking about. Anyway some point outs are really good and valid :)

Comment: with just the code you posted you don't need the outer loop as you only match the contact.EmailAddress against the one from the outer loop. If you do more stuff around this you might need a HashMap with email addresses to avoid nested loops

Comment: Inside the inner loop I am using it, in the if statement. `email.equals(contact.EmailAddress)`, what do you mean I don't need that outer loop? As I need to accumulate the `count` for each email address...

Comment: @OndrejTokar if you need to traverse all that data, wouldn't be easier and faster to retrieve all the data in a single query and then work with that bunch of data in memory rather than querying the datasource several times?

Comment: In the inner loop you get an email address from your contact. The only thing you do with the email from the outer loop is checking if it matches the inner one. If not, you continue to the next inner one. So basically you ignore each inner one n-1 times (for n outer emails) and once do something. So you could do just the inner loop and check if there is one matching email address for your contact.

Comment: But I have several emails which I need to check. Not only one. I wish you were right and I could get it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what do you mean? I am not querying the data.

Answer (score 2):

- Never include in a loop operation that can be done outside it. (already mentioned)
- Look where you duplicate your code or check the same condition more than once

> if(queryStringActivity !=null && ....)
>
> .....
>
> else if(queryStringActivity==null || ...))

- Don't be afraid to create new methods (JIT can inline methods) so there will be no efficiency loss
- Try to use recursion instead of iteration (recursion is from God, iteration from programmer) (It's a pity that even Java8 lacks tail recursion, but it is a good practice).

Comment: Thank you for a good and valid input. I haven't done anything with recursion yet, but heard a lot about it. Probably it's time to use it! :)